# copy/paste row n number of times (according to value from cell)

Tags: vba, excel

I need a code where cells from column 8 & 14 will be concatenated and copied to another sheet (ofc in first empty cell) but they need to be copied n number of times. Depending on value from cell in column 23.

So each copy will be the same, but copied one below other.

For example:

I have RIF50G 2B in "H2" and MAEU3P in "N2". In "W2" I have "4". So I need this in another sheet:

```
RIF50G 2B MAEU3P    
RIF50G 2B MAEU3P    
RIF50G 2B MAEU3P    
RIF50G 2B MAEU3P
```

If value in colUmn "W" is 0 that row does not need to be copied!

Data from all cells mentioned above will be refreshed and each time I run the code, values and strings will be different (it is just a part from larger code where I import some data)

Also, when it finish copying first row this way, I need that to be done for every row until last one.

Comment: What have you tried so far and how has your approach not worked? In order to get answers to your question, you should create a small and easy to understand example so that others can copy/paste it into their IDE in order to easily help you track down a specific error.

Comment: There are so many small questions that could have been answered if you had volunteered the code that you had tried (working or not).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple [Range.Resize](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa176182%28v=office.11%29.aspx) based on the value in column W should be enough to repeat the concatenated values.

```
Dim rw As Long
With Worksheets("Sheet1")
    For rw = 2 To .Cells(Rows.Count, "W").End(xlUp).Row
        If CBool(.Cells(rw, "W").Value2) Then _
            Worksheets("another sheet").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Resize(.Cells(rw, "W").Value2, 1) = _
                .Cells(rw, "H").Value2 & Chr(32) & .Cells(rw, "N").Value2
    Next rw
End With
```